# How to dermine if a value of type int is a match in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, int

Here is the code I have so far

```
    int []d = {2,18,4,4,6,8,10}; 
    int matchNumber = 4 ;
    i=0 ;

    for(i= 0; (match==d[i])&&(i < MAX_SIZE-1); i++); 
    { 
    if(matchNumber==d[i]) 
    { 
    System.out.println("Match number " + matchNumber + " appears in array d at index " + d[i]);

    }
    else 
    {

    System.out.print("-1");}
    }
```

If the int is a match I have to display the first index it appears in the array, if not I have to display -1. It seems like this is how it should be written but I just keep getting a -1 as an answer. How do I keep the same type of format because I am limited on what I can use to get the correct output.

Comment: what is `match==d[i]` in the for loop condition supposed to do?

Comment: it was supposed to be

Comment: it was supposed to be         matchNumber==d[i]

Comment: By now peeskillet gave you some alternative implementations, but the only thing you really have to change in your program is to write
`matchNumber!=d[i]` instead of `matchNumber==d[i]` in the loop condition and it should work.

Comment: ... and of course change d[i] to i in the `println` statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Appears at index `i` not `d[i]`. That's the problem. `i` is your index. That's what you want printed out, not the value, `d[i]`. I the index is printed, `break` the loop.

2) Also, you shouldn't have the `println("-1");` inside the loop. You only want it printed out if the value is not found. So I added a boolean statement. If the value is found it eqauls true. If not found, then I have a print statement to print -1.

3) Also, maybe you just want `i < d.length` as you stopping statement in the loop.

4) Another huge problem is the `;` at the end of your `for` loop. I fixed that too. The `;` ends the loop even before it starts.

5) Also, you don't need the `i = 0` outside of your loop. I added the `int i = 0` declaration inside of the loop. If you wanted to keep it the way you had, then the `i = 0` should be `int i = 0;`

```
int []d = {2,18,4,4,6,8,10}; 
int matchNumber = 4 ;
boolean found = false;
for(i= 0; i < d.length; i++)
{ 
    if(matchNumber==d[i]) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Match number " + matchNumber 
                       + " appears in array d at index " + i);
        found = true;
        break;

    }
}

if (!found) System.out.println("-1");
```

**Edit: Using a while loop**

```
int []d = {2,18,4,4,6,8,10}; 
int matchNumber = 4 ;
boolean found = false;

int i = 0;
while (!found && i < d.length) {
    if (matchNumber == d[i]){
        System.out.println("Match number " + matchNumber 
                          + " appears in array d at index " + i);
        found = true;
    }
    i++;
}

if (!found) System.out.println("-1");
```

Comment: I am still getting the negative value and the break message is displaying an error

Comment: `break` only works inside of a loop. If you have the `;` at the end of your `for` loop statement, there will be no loop home for the `break`, hence the error.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept answer if it helped solve your problem in question. (the check mark below the down vote);

Comment: I corrected all the errors and still the same output. I prefer not to use the break statement because my professor does not like it to be used.

Comment: Ok if you don't want to use the break, the more natural way is to use a `while` loop. I'll make the fix in an edit.

Comment: I didn't fix one of the mistakes. I didn't use the break and it worked fine. Thanks

Comment: @peeskillet: While your answer is completely correct, the orignal program structure is not as wrong as you think, if you leave the semicolon after the for loop and make a minimal change to the loop's condition (see my later answer). But granted: whether this was intended by the OP or not is hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean flag to determine if you need to continue looking for a match or not. That's a more *natural* approach than using a break statement.

```
int []d = {2,18,4,4,6,8,10}; 
int matchNumber = 4 ;

boolean matched = false;

for(i= 0; i < d.length && !matched; i++)
{ 
    if(matchNumber==d[i]) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Match number " + matchNumber + " appears in array d at index " + i);
        matched = true;
    }
}

if(!matched) {
    System.out.println("-1");
}
```

Comment: Who mentioned OP? That's even valid for structural programming.

Comment: Who said anything about programming paradigms?

Comment: OP refers to the poster.

Comment: Oh, then it's my bad. But why it wouldn't work as he wants? I'm missing something

Comment: Also for reference, we use OP because we do not know if user is male or female.

Comment: I don't know why but I am still getting the negative one value as an output. I preferred to use the Boolean expression to get the correct output but is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the structure of your solution doesn't have to be changed so much (no break, while or nested statements necessary). However, (aside from your typos) your formatting is pretty strange and makes it difficult to decide, whether the semicolon after the for loop was intended or not. Here is a solution with minimal changes to your original program:

```
int []d = {2,18,4,4,6,8,10}; 
int matchNumber = 4 ;
int i=0 ;

for(i= 0; (matchNumber!=d[i])&&(i < d.length() ); i++); 

if(matchNumber==d[i]) 
{ 
    System.out.println("Match number "+matchNumber+" appears in array d at index "+i);
}
else 
{
    System.out.print("-1");
}
```

What I did was to

- replace `match==d[i])&&(i < MAX_SIZE-1)` with `(matchNumber!=d[i])&&(i < d.length() )` in the loop header
- replace `d[i]` with `ì` in the `println` statement
- delete one unnecessary set of brackets after the `for` statement

Comment: You also, may be right, but if you were a teach looking at this approach, how would you comment?

Comment: First of all, excuse me for repeating my answer at three different locations.

Comment: As I said, I'm not sure, what the OP's intentions were. Formatting and brackets pointed in one way and the actual code in the other and my first intention was the same as your's. However, I've gained some experience in correcting student written code and - by now - before making too drastic changes I first try to find out whether the student simply tried a different approach I haven't though of.